# Want to move a slider and all the others update in Matlab?

Tags: user-interface, matlab, matlab-guide

I have GUI in Matlab that I have made using the Programmatic approach. It has 6 sliders and I want to be able to move one of them and have the others update as if i clicked them again but to stay in the same place. I am guessing I will need to use the set() function. Is there some function to do this in matlab already? I have been looking around. Any suggestions or something to point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `guide`, you can access the other sliders from the `handles` variable that is available in each callback.

Set the `Value` property for them.

```
   function Slider1_CallBack(hObj,evt,handles)
       set(handles.Slider1,'Value',10);
       set(handles.Slider2,'Value',10);
      % etc..
   end
```

In case you are using it programmaticaly, you can store the `handles` manually.

```
   function main
        handles.Figure1 = figure(..);
        handles.Slider1 = uicontrol(...);
        handles.Slider2 = uicontrol(...);
        guidata(handles.Figure1,handles);
   end
```

And your slider callback should be:

```
   function Slider1_CallBack(hObj,evt)
       handles = guidata(hObj);
       set(handles.Slider1,'Value',10);
       set(handles.Slider2,'Value',10);
      % etc..
   end
```

**Edit** A good practice in writing UI is separating the GUI logic from the actual data. You always change the data, and call `updateGUI` routine.

Therefore, you can write your program like this:

```
   function main
        handles.gui.Figure1 = figure(..);
        handles.gui.Slider1 = uicontrol(...);
        handles.gui.Slider2 = uicontrol(...);

        handles.data.x = 1;
        guidata(handles.Figure1,handles);
   end

   function UpdateGui(handles)
        %Based on the data, update the GUI
        set(handles.Slider1,'Value',handles.data.x);
        set(handles.Slider2,'Value',handles.data.x+1);
   end
```

And the callback should look like:

```
   function Slider1_CallBack(hObj,evt)
       handles = guidata(hObj);
       handles.data.x = handles.data.x  + 1;
       UpdateGui(handles);
       guidata(hObj,handles);
      % etc..
   end
```

Comment: I am doing it programatically.

Comment: I see how this approach works but wont you end up with a lot of duplicate code?

Comment: Yeah thats more of what I had in mind a function that updates all the sliders with passed data.